# Is there anyway to update IL instructions to use new local variable indexes?

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

I am trying to inject a method into another method.
Problem is the local variables indexes.
Example-

```
 public void Method1()
    {
        var tes = "anything";

    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        var spring = 40;

    }
```

I want to inject method1 into method2 but the problem is it throws invalid IL code because for method1 **local variable** at **index 0** is of type **string** and for method2 **local variable** at **index 0** is of type **int**.
What I do is I fetch method1 **methodDefinition** and takes its instructuions through-

```
  var Method1_Instructions= MethodDefinition.Body.Instructions.ToList();// method1 methodDefinition
var Method1_localVariables= Method1_MethodDefinition.Body.Variables
   for (var I = 0; I < Method1_localVariables.Count; I++)
                    {
                        Method2_MethodDefinition.Body.Variables.Insert(I,
                            Method1_localVariables[I]); 

                    }
```

I add the local variables of method1 to method2 variables list and also insert instructions before it.
But I know its wrong IL code because of the local variables index issue.
So, How can I fix it without writing the IL code myself?

Comment: can't you just add a call instead the full method's code?

Comment: No, What I have posted is just a simple code to explain the problem. In my original code I can't just call another another method. There is some data that also needs to be passed.
I can for sure find a workaround to but is it not solvable as it is now?
I mean I can't just copy instructions and inject to another method. Isn't there any code that can fix the local variable indexes or instructions?